# Protractor expect specific text siblings of selector

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing, siblings

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    ...
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="radio-inline">
                <input name="sms_provider" type="radio" value="2" id="2">
                <label class="text-gray-dark" for="2"> </label>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td data-label="Server name">ServerA3</td>
        <td data-label="Description"></td>
        <td data-label="Status">
            <label class="text-success">
                <clr-icon shape="check"></clr-icon>
                Default
            </label>
        </td>
        <td data-label="Actions">
            <a href="http://example.com/public/smsconfigurations/2/edit" data-tooltip="Edit Server">
                <clr-icon shape="pencil" size="22" style="width: 22px; height: 22px;"></clr-icon>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    ...
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now I wanna to check `ServerA3` has `Default` status or no. As matter of fact I expect `ServerA3` has `Default` text as siblings. What should I do?

I try with this code, but it doesn't work:

```
expect(element(by.xpath('//td[contains(text(), "ServerA3")]')).getWebElement().getDriver().findElement(by.css('*[data-label="status"]')).getText()).toContain('Default');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var status = element(by.xpath('//tr[td[.="ServerA3"]]/td[@data-label="Status"]'))
            .getAttribute('innerText');

expect(status).toEqual('Default')
```